# Problem with the update of a backend transaction in javascript to promote restaurant products

Tags: javascript, frontend, backend, react-fullstack

I made a transaction to promote the product of a restaurant
style when I create a product if I can promote it
but when I edit the product with the promote button it does not update it well
I get the error 500 of the transaction function
and I have checked it and it has no faults.

When I do the transaction of the promote button with the restaurants, it works fine for me, but when I implement it with the products, it gives me an error 500 of the function of the promote transaction[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO1dZ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUxrb.jpg)

What I try is that when I press the promote button, a product from a restaurant is promoted and if there is another from the same restaurant that is promoted, the promotion is removed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtRe3.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.